# The format was not applied in excel sheet

Tags: c#, excel, winforms, formatting

I'm working WinformsApplication, in that application i have a grid control. In GridControl i have a double type column with format "F2". When i tried to export the grid to excel, the format (F2) is displayed instead of value(e.g 55.78).

But **if i set the format as (0.00) instead of (F2). Its working fine**.

Please let me know ,why "F2" format is not applied? or whether "F2" can be supported by excel?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The Excel file format specification **does not define** those [standard numeric format strings from .NET framework](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k(v=vs.110).aspx), in other words it **does not use** "C" for currency, "D" for decimal, "F" for fixed-point, etc..
Instead it defines the following: [numFmt (Number Format)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff529356(v=office.12).aspx).

Now the specification is probably a bit hard to follow so instead I would suggest you to take a look at this office article: [Create or delete a custom number format](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Create-or-delete-a-custom-number-format-78f2a361-936b-4c03-8772-09fab54be7f4).

In short, you'll need to use the format strings which are compatible with Excel's specification.
So instead of `"F2"`, you'll need to use `"0.00"`.